# Select2 & Gravity Forms. How to target multiple select fields. CSS class does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using select2 on multiple Gravity forms with many select fields. The Select2 configuration for all select fields is the same but I can't seem to apply the script to all select fields and instead have to target each one using IDs.

What I'm having to do:

```
$('#input_4_0').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  width:'100%'
});
$('#input_4_1').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  width:'100%'
});


$('#input_4_2').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  width:'100%'
});
```

What I'd like to do:

```
$('.js-select select').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  width:'100%'
});
```

Have tried everything but nothing other than unique IDs works? Any help would be great

Comment: i give you a solution with id beginning by the same string..to fix your problem with the class js-select, show your html code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this syntax, the selector `^` is equivalent to startwith:

```
// select all id beginning with input_4
$('[id^=input_4]').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
  width:'100%'
});
```

Comment: This is great, I modified it slightly by removing the 4 so now it will take any input with an id starting with 'input_'. Many thanks for your help